# Why Windows systems are not suitable(production mode) for Key/Value DB

Tags: windows, redis, nosql

Why many key/value database systems such as Redis,FoundationDB even [ssdb](http://ssdb.io/docs/install.html)
in Windows system are not recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they're typically developed, optimized, tested and primarily used on Linux/OSX. However the [Windows version of Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows) is a high quality port that's only a minor version point behind the official distribution which passes all of [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) test suite so is a suitable substitute for the Linux version if you only have access to Windows servers.

Answer (score 2):

There is Windows implementation of REDIS. Try to use https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows and https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads

Where have you read that this implementation is not recommended?

Comment: Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/interoperability/archive/2013/04/22/redis-on-windows-stable-and-reliable.aspx ., please.